# What could cause a Docker build step cache to be invalidated even though the previous step is cached?

Tags: docker

The relevant Dockerfile parts are:

```
COPY --from=builder /srv/pnpm-lock.yaml .
RUN pnpm fetch --production
```

If we look at the build log:

```
#21 [runner 6/9] COPY --from=builder /srv/pnpm-lock.yaml .
#21 CACHED

#22 [runner 7/9] RUN pnpm fetch --production
#22 sha256:30f9f1937ac26c0bee1bf1f43bc2cdf011b7dbe3274259fa3a38207eb7c134d8 3.23kB / ...
#22 sha256:9515600f9c042af6514cc6ee2a695846114c98f7ccb408866f8c0335b3ad8249 278.35MB / 278.35MB 2.1s done
#22 DONE 2.2s
```

Given that `COPY --from=builder /srv/pnpm-lock.yaml .` I would expect that `RUN pnpm fetch --production` is also going to be cached.

For context, the build command is:

```bash
docker buildx build \
  --progress plain \
  --file apps/contra-api/Dockerfile \
  --push \
  --tag redacted/contrawork/contra-api/review:cd6b0550 \
  --cache-to type=registry,ref=redacted/contrawork/contra-api/review:cd6b0550-build-cache,mode=max,compression=zstd \
  --cache-from type=registry,ref=redacted/contrawork/contra-api/review:cd6b0550-build-cache \
  --cache-to type=registry,ref=redacted/contrawork/contra-api/review:latest_review-build-cache,mode=max,compression=zstd \
  --cache-from type=registry,ref=redacted/contrawork/contra-api/review:latest_review-build-cache \
  --build-arg RELEASE_VERSION=cd6b0550 \
  --secret id=env,src=/home/github/actions-runner/_work/gaia/gaia/.env .
```

What causes `pnpm fetch --production` to be invalidated?

Comment: What is in the Dockerfile?  (Is that the very first `RUN` command?)

Comment: What would be the relevance of the surrounding Dockerfile context if the preceding `RUN` command is shown to be cached? i.e. isn't cache linear based on the last command execution?

Comment: I have a hypothesis here around the `ARG` value mattering.  Is `ARG RELEASE_VERSION` fairly early in the Dockerfile, and does moving it after this `RUN` line make a difference?

Comment: `ARG RELEASE_VERSION` exists only at the very end of the Dockerfile; after these `RUN` commands.